# loop through properties in object and populate it

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am trying to loop through the properties in an object and apply it a string.

For example to do it dynamically will be:

```
Dim objAnswers As New DAL.Quiz.QuizAnswers
    With objAnswers
        .Question1 = "text1"
        .Question2 = "text2"
        .Question3 = "text3"
        .Question4 = "text4"
        .Question5 = "text5"
    End With
```

But i am trying to loop through the properties of the object, and then apply it like so:

```
Dim objAnswers As New DAL.Quiz.QuizAnswers
    For Each rptItem As RepeaterItem In repeater1.Items
        Dim ddlAnswers As App_Controls_Forms_DropDownList = CType(rptItem.FindControl("DropDownList1"), App_Controls_Forms_DropDownList)
        For Each p As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In objAnswers.GetType().GetProperties()
            If p.ToString.StartsWith("question") Then
                p = ddlAnswers.SelectedText
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

The string i am trying to populate the object with s from a dropdownlist in a repeater. Here is what i am trying to do in pseudo - for each row in the repeater, take the text from the dropdownlist and populate the object properties which begin with "question"

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**

```
Dim objAnswers As New DAL.Quiz.QuizAnswers
    For Each p As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In objAnswers.GetType().GetProperties()
        For Each rptItem As RepeaterItem In repeater1.Items
            Dim ddlAnswers As App_Controls_Forms_DropDownList = CType(rptItem.FindControl("DropDownList1"), App_Controls_Forms_DropDownList)
            If p.ToString.StartsWith("Question") Then
                p.SetValue(objAnswers, ddlAnswers.SelectedText)
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: You should be testing the `Name` of the `PropertyInfo` and `StartsWith` is case-sensitive.  You then need to call `SetValue` on the `PropertyInfo` to set the value of that property.

Comment: If you are looking for most exotic usage of asp.net controls then you are on right way. Else apply KISS principle (Keep It Simple, Stupid). All you try in this and previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53696088/retrieving-values-from-controls-within-repeater) can be coded in 10 to 20 lines of C# code.

Comment: Do you realize that your code would set all Question properties to the same value?

Comment: @jmcilhinney please see editted question for progress, what parameters do i give the SetValue? it is returning a null value

Comment: @jmoreno If i flip my for each (please see editted question for progress) this would fix it?

Comment: @jmoreno This doesn't appear to fix it, any ideas on how i could loop through both?

Comment: Maybe you should look at using a List instead.

Comment: You can "improve" your code but the problem is that the solution is structurally incorrect. No `Reflection` stuff can help.

Comment: See my answer for both your questions.

Comment: No, all of your properties start with question, they are all going to be set to the same value.  And Alex is correct, the basic problem is structural: reflection is used to match unknown properties with unknown values.  You know the properties and have enough information to map one to the other without using the reflection. Reflection is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use vb so some names might be wrong. I would loop the items, find the single matching property and set it as follows:

```
Dim objAnswers As New DAL.Quiz.QuizAnswers
Dim i as Integer
For i = 0 To repeater1.Items.Length - 1
    Dim ddlAnswers As App_Controls_Forms_DropDownList = CType(repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("DropDownList1"), App_Controls_Forms_DropDownList)
    Dim p as System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = objAnswers.GetType().GetProperty("Question" & i + 1)
    p.SetValue(objAnswers, ddlAnswers.SelectedText)
Next
```

Comment: MATE THANK YOU SO MUCH! works like a charm! You dont use vb but clearly know a lot well done!! fyi its repeater.items.count and repeater.items(i) not [] but works perfectly thankk you!

Comment: another quick question, if i was to do the reverse and set the value of the parameter to the dropdownlist will it be getValue, but asks for an object as the second parameter.. any solutions?

Comment: It may be an answer to this **x/y** question. Not real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is (over)simplified solution for both your questions.

```
--DB structure
create table dbo.questions(
id int identity(1,1) primary key,
question nvarchar(100) not null,
correctAnswerId int null --single correct answer
)
go
create table dbo.answers(
id int identity(1,1) primary key,
questionId int not null,
answer nvarchar(100) not null,
--isCorrect bit default 0 -- multiple correct answers
foreign key(questionId) references dbo.questions(id)
)
go
alter table dbo.questions
add constraint fk_questions_answers foreign key (correctAnswerId) references dbo.answers(id)

//.aspx page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int questions = 0;
        int correct = 0;
        //int questionId // if you want to save it
        //int answerId // if you want to save it
        foreach(RepeaterItem item in rpQuestions.Items)
        {
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                questions++;
                string correctAnswerId = ((Literal)item.FindControl("correctAnswerId")).Text;
                var answerList = item.FindControl("lstAnswers") as RadioButtonList;
                if (answerList.SelectedValue == correctAnswerId)
                    correct++;
            }
        }
        result.Text = string.Format("{0} correct answers out of {1}", correct, questions);
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>quiz ver 0.0</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rpQuestions" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlQuestions">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Literal ID="questionId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("id") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Literal>
                    <asp:Literal ID="correctAnswerId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("correctAnswerId") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Literal>
                    <h2><asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("question") %>'></asp:Literal></h2>
                    <%-- radio buttons are easier to use than dropdown --%>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="lstAnswers" runat="server" DataTextField="answer" DataValueField="id" DataSourceID="sqlAnswers"></asp:RadioButtonList>
                    <%-- Bind possible answers declarativelly --%>

                    <%-- This DataSource must be inside ItemTemplate --%>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlAnswers" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnection %>"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT id, answer FROM dbo.answers where questionId=@questionId">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter Name="questionId" ControlID="questionId" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlQuestions" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnection %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT id, question, correctAnswerId FROM questions"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit answers" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
            <div>
                <asp:Literal ID="result" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already know what properties you are going to set, you don’t need reflection:

```
Dim objAnswers As New DAL.Quiz.QuizAnswers
Dim answers = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
Dim i as Integer
For i = 0 To repeater1.Items.Length - 1
    Dim ddlAnswers = CType(repeater1.Items(i).
         FindControl("DropDownList1"), App_Controls_Forms_DropDownList)        
    answers.Add("Question" & i + 1,  ddlAnswers.SelectedText)
Next

objAnswers.Question1=answers(NameOf(objAnswers.Question1))
objAnswers.Question2=answers(NameOf(objAnswers.Question2))
objAnswers.Question3=answers(NameOf(objAnswers.Question3))
objAnswers.Question4=answers(NameOf(objAnswers.Question4))
objAnswers.Question5=answers(NameOf(objAnswers.Question5))
```

Even better would be to have a constructor that takes a dictionary, and set the properties from there.